# Form in mediaWiki

Tags: forms, mediawiki

I have a Mediawiki site running. I am a beginner at this. I want two pages:  one to display name and has a button, which leads to the another page where we can add names. This page has a textbox and a button to save the name. The display page has to show all the names entered.Please advice on how this can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a beginner, I would not add *buttons* - just use the features MediaWiki already provides. On page 1, add a link using:

```
[[name of second page]]
```

On the second page, people can add names and use default MediaWiki functionality to save them.

To make the names nicely formatted, use a [table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTables).